# Woocommerce how to alter shipping tax before checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using a Woocommerce Multi Currency plugin and it calculates all the prices for products in an order and the shipping costs properly. However, shipping costs are converted to proper values. In all the plugins that I have used regarding multi currency, the taxes are calculated based on default currency.

For example, let's say default shipping cost is 3 EUR and I set the currency to Czech Krons, resulting in the following value for shipping 76.10 CZK. If shipping tax is 20%, the shipping code should be 15.22 CZK but the value is calculated based on EUR value, resulting in 0.6 CZK.

What hook or action can I use to change the shipping tax before checkout?

Thanks!